# Need to create a report based on the two defined product if present in the opportunity line item

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, joined-reports

Need some help in creating a report which will provide all oppty which has product1 and product2 in their opportynity line item. Product 1 and Produc 2 will be an AND condition so that it only shows opportunity which has the two products only.

If any oppty has only product1 , it shouldnot show in the report and similarly if any oppty has product2 , it should not show in the report. The oppty which has both the products should be only returned in the report.

I used the report type as Opportunity with products

***I tried to create two filters with product name contains 'Product1' and Product name contains 'Product2' but once I ran the report it returned nothing. This filter is not checking both the rows it checks against one row line item record.***

Any idea how to proced in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This query is not possible using Reports

The workaround is to have use Roll up Summary (RSF) fields (or you can use [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)) on Opportunity that counts the presence of child OpportunityLineItem of specific Products. Then you can filter on Opportunity fields

**Hack-y solution that works in some use cases**:

DLRS allows for fields to be concatenated into a string so as long as the product names are short and there aren't too many products per Opportunity, you could, in many cases, simply DLRS roll up the productnames into a concatenated field and then query where ConcatenatedField__c contains 'P1' and contains 'P2' and Product Count = 2 (another RSF)

Comment: Thanks ! I will look at the DLRS , I haven't worked on that earlier. I will check that out